# Localstorage not saving data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Whenever I refresh the page, I instantly logout and localstorage lose all it's data. How to fix that?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setAuthToken(window.localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
    setAuthTokenType(window.localStorage.getItem('authTokenType'))
    setUsername(window.localStorage.getItem('username'))
    setUserId(window.localStorage.getItem('userId'))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    authToken
      ? window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', authToken)
      : window.localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
    authTokenType
      ? window.localStorage.setItem('authTokenType', authTokenType)
      : window.localStorage.removeItem('authTokenType')
    username
      ? window.localStorage.setItem('username', username)
      : window.localStorage.removeItem('username')
    userId
      ? window.localStorage.setItem('userId', userId)
      : window.localStorage.removeItem('userId')

  }, [authToken, authTokenType, userId, username])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove the localStorage items within this useEffect context.

Because `useEffect` will get called initially before assigning any values to state variables since the initial values of the states are null.

Comment: it works, but now I got 401 if I try to post something after refresh

Comment: see if tokens are attached to the API

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works!

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setAuthToken(window.localStorage.getItem('authToken'));
    setAuthTokenType(window.localStorage.getItem('authTokenType'));
    setUserId(window.localStorage.getItem('userId'));
    setUsername(window.localStorage.getItem('username'))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
          authToken && window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', authToken)
          authTokenType && window.localStorage.setItem('authTokenType', authTokenType)
          userId && window.localStorage.setItem('userId', userId)
          username && window.localStorage.setItem('username', username)
      }, [authToken, authTokenType, userId])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).